# input:empty detects empty fields when there are none

Tags: javascript, jquery

Using the below I am checking every input field is not empty

```
  if ( $("input:empty").length > 0 )
  {
  $(":text[value=]").css('background', 'rgb(255,220,200)'); 
  $(":text[value!=]").css('background', 'rgb(255,255,255)'); 
  alert('One or more fields are not completed') 
  e.preventDefault();
  return false;     
  }
```

Even when all fields are full I still get an alert. What are the gotchas here? No fields highlight. I did try to extract which field it is but it came back with nothing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

:empty does not refer to whether or not an input has content. It refers to whether or not a node has children. Since I don't imagine you have put anything INSIDE your input tags, it's working just fine ;)

From the [docs](http://api.jquery.com/empty-selector/):

> **Description**: Select all elements that have no children (including text nodes).

try `if ( $('input:text[value=""]').length > 0 )`

[example](http://jsfiddle.net/dtX6C/2/)

Answer (score 1):

I believe the value attribute comparison is comparing the original `value` attribute.

Try...

```
$(":text").filter(function() {
    return $.trim(this.value);
});
```

This will drop all text inputs from the set that only contain whitespace.